# How to use Sed to replace all characters in between colons

Tags: shell-script, sed

How to replace all characters between colons using `sed`?

```
# replace easy with 123
sed:easy:abc -> sed:123:abc

# replace hardest with 123
sed:hardest:efg -> sed:123:efg

# replace magnificent with zyx
sed:magnificent:zyx -> sed:123:zyx
```

Comment: This is one of the most basic `sed` functions. Have you tried this yourself? What went wrong?. Update the question with your `sed` invocation, and the error message you got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$ sed -e 's/:[^:]*:/:123:/' file
sed:123:abc
sed:123:efg
sed:123:zyx
```

Comment: awesome never thought so fast and accurate answer from this site thx~~

Comment: Why the `-e` option?

Comment: @confused00: It's just my habit.